# Transform 2 columns with numbers into a new date column in Power Query

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I have a table with 2 columns in number format (MONTH and YEAR) And I want to add a date columns with the year, month and last day of the month so I tried this and gives me an error:

`= Table.AddColumn(#"table", "Dates", each #date(Date.EndOfMonth([Month]),[Month],[Year]) as date)`

Anybody knows how to figure it out? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let a = #date([Year], [Month], 1), 
b = Date.EndOfMonth(a)
in b
```

[image]